# How to get previous TOKEN_RULE in visitTerminal?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

For this grammar :

```
ACTION_ESCAPE
   : EscAny -> type (ACTION_CONTENT)
```

In visitTerminal(TerminalNode node), the call to `ANTLRv4Lexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(node.getSymbol().getType())` gives me the token name `ACTION_CONTENT`, but how can I get `ACTION_ESCAPE`/`EscAny` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the type of the rule that matched the input `EscAny` since you explicitly changed the token value to `ACTION_CONTENT`. The only way to identify a token is the token type.

If you want the original type then don't replace it in the first place.